# Am I able to trigger an event from Spring Boot that can use JavaScript or something else to update an image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-boot

I need to be able to update an image on a website thats in HTML while using Spring Boot as a backend. Right now I'm using JavaScript to update the image after a set amount of time but it's not in time with when the image is updated in my database making it skip some of them. It also uses a lot of requests to the server and I don't know if that is good or bad. Is there a way to be able to send an event from java to javascript or use a javascript function in java to update the image. I've tried looking it up before but I haven't found anything that has done exactly what I needed it to do. Some of the stuff have found doesn't work in my project either.

I've tried using eval engine in java to use a javascript function in java but I never got it to work. I made a loop in javascript to request an api url to retrieve the image from the databse but it was off time. That's all I've been able to try and nothing else has been close to what I needed to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use WebSocket to establish connections between the frontend and the backend so that you can push notification to frontend and reflect the changes. This too has its own complexity like managing all the connections. This is only recommended if you really need real time reflections or else what you are doing is fine.